# How to select data by monthly and weekly and quarterly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the an `Order` model in the following

If today is 5/3

and I want to sum the previous 3 months data of order, how to do it ?

I mean I want to show the  `2/1 ~ 4/30` excluding the orders in May.

If today is 2014/4/20, and I want to show the sum of previous 3 weeks data. `2014/2/1~2/15`

How to do it in Rubic way ?

Comment: You always want to start from the beginning of the month, right? Say if we're only the second week of Feb, you don't want to add weeks from January as well, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something along the lines:

```
date = DateTime.now.utc
Order.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_month, date.utc.end_of_month).sum('price')
```

Where `price` is the column you want to sum.

You can reuse the logic of @Santosh in order to get the dates you want =)

Answer (score 2):

```
start_date = 3.months.ago.beginning_of_month
end_date = 1.month.ago.end_of_month
```

You can write your query based on these dates. Same logic can be applied for weeks also.